# YII2 Выводить только тех врачей, специальность которых выбрана

Tags: php, yii2

есть таблица `workers` с полями `id_w`, `FIO`, `id_tos`

есть таблица `type_of_serves` с полями `id`, `type` (связаны по `id_tos` и `id`)

```html
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
                           'fieldConfig' => [
                               'options' => ['class' => 'login100-form validate-form p-b-33 p-t-10']
                            ],
                          ]);
?>

<div class="col-lg-10 login100-form validate-form p-b-33 p-t-5" style="margin-left: 8%;">
  <?= $form->field($model, 'FIO')->label('ФИО'); ?>
  <?= $form->field($model, 'telefone')->label('Телефон'); ?>
  <?= $form->field($model, 'type_of_serves')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(TypeOfSrevese::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'type'))->label('Выберите услугу'); ?>
  <?= $form->field($model, 'id_w')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Workers::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id_w', 'FIO'))->label('Выберите врача'); ?>
  <?= $form->field($model, 'date')->textInput(['type' => 'date'])->label('Выберите дату'); ?>
  <?= Html::submitButton('Записаться', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']); ?>
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [это расширение](https://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/depdrop).
Вы, как мне показалось, новичок, поэтому сами такое будете очень долго писать. Поэтому ставьте расширение более опытного разработчика и быстрее продвинетесь дальше :-)